# Sending e-mail attachment from MS Office

Tags: ms-office

There's an option in MS Office 2011 for Mac programs that allows to send current document as an e-mail attachment. However in my case this option is inactive:

[image]

I can't find any option to setup e-mail client in Word/Excel preferences. How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the Office suite up to date? You might want to check for updates and check to see if the issue still exists?

Comment: I've checked it and it's up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh ! I think I have seen this before

Try the following:

Start Apple Mail

1. Go to Mail>Preferences>General
2. The top line that reads "Default Email Reader" must show either Outlook or    Mail.
3. If it doesn't, please go ahead and change it.

you might have google set as of now.

Hope this works!

Comment: you have any luck?